# Find a Div's margin value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, margin

I want to be able to rightclick a Div, and then find it's margin's value. The Div's are created like this.

//create spaces//

```
var addLeft=75;
var addTop=105;
var vert = 1;
var horz = 1;
var selectedunit = "";

for (var i = 1; i<26; i++) {
    $("#background").append("<div class='areas' id = 'space" + vert + horz + "' style ='position: absolute; LEFT: " + addLeft + "px; Top:" + addTop + "px'></div>");

    if (addLeft < 600) {
        addLeft += 150;
        vert+=1;
    } else {
        horz+=1;
        addTop += 150;
        addLeft = 75;
        vert=1;
    }
}
```

And I try to find the div's margin with this.

```
    $('.areas').mousedown(function(e) {
    if(e.button === 2 ){
           var style = window.getComputedStyle(this);
            var futureleft = style.marginLeft;
            $('#Status').append(futureleft);
      }
     })
```

Status is just a box that should give me the Div's left value, but it always gives 0PX. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, why not do

```
var futureleft = $(this).css("marginLeft");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting any margin. You are assigning a `left` value:

```
"LEFT: " + addLeft + "px;
```

But asking for the `marginLeft` value, which was not defined in the generated divs:

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(this);
var futureleft = style.marginLeft;
```

Either you set the `margin-left` on the generated divs, or you request the correct property:

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(this);
var futureleft = style.left;
```

Comment: Ah, so the style Left isn't the same as marginLeft. Thank you.